# PhoneGap BUILD and phonegap-facebook-plugin sample

Tags: facebook, cordova, build, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I want to use the phonegap-facebook-plugin in a PhoneGap **BUILD** application.

The documentation [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/master/platforms/pg-build) only explains how to add the plugin into the config file but does not explain how to actually use it.

More specifically,

1. does anyone have experience with this plugin and PhoneGap Build or
   for that matter any other plugin? Sample code?
2. what version of the "facebookConnectPlugin.js" should I use? (there
   are several of those in the project)
3. during the development phase I
   am testing in the browser first and then on the phone. How do I make
   it work in both environments?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to test phonegap-facebook-plugin in browser. There are some other plugins for facebook integration using phonegap.

Comment: can you provide a link to said plugin(s)? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Actually, if you go [here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), the author has the example of the usage there.
2. The version you're looking at was deprecated. Use `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" source="npm" spec="1.4.0">` instead.
3. You have to add your localhost to Facebook app settings.